# How did gladiators/assyrians kill large predators in single combat?

Tags: ancient-history, animals, gladiators

Bears & lions & other megafauna are super powerful and dangerous animals, even many smaller caliber guns can't pierce their skin. They're also too fast and too strong to easily subdue with traps & stuff.

So basically, if I was an Assyrian king or a gladiator, how would I defend myself against large predators like bears or lions with just a spear or sword?

I've tried to look up how gladiators fought predators but all I could find is what KINDS of animals they fought, what they used to fight them, and how they fought other humans, not anything about how they killed large predators like bears or lions.

Comment: Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions. Please revise your question to document your preliminary research.

Comment: Why do you assume that early humans hunted megafauna?  Why would they need to defend against them?  This question seems to be based on lots of assumptions with very little supporting evidence.  Check [Wikipedia:LionHunting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lion_hunting) and [WIkipedia:BearHunting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bear_hunting) and [Wikipedia:Ainu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ainu_people) or [InuitHunting](https://www.latimes.com/archives/la-xpm-2003-apr-20-adfg-polar20-story.html)  "

Comment: @MCW What do you mean "why do you assume" we know for a fact humans hunted Mammoths and north american natives hunted bears for food*. Not to mention that these animals are dangerous and would cause a lot of harm to early communities if they just decided not to defend against them. Also, Roman standard bearers wore the skins of lions often.*https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bear_hunting#North_America

Comment: @MCW Those articles don't really help, they just say what they used to kill animals, not how exactly they did it or techniques they used, which is what I'm asking

Comment: I just re-read the articles; they describe spears, snares, and bows.

Comment: @MCW but how exactly did they use them to kill the bears and lions? Based on what I read it doesn't say. & also, the the inuit one describes a modern hunt, with rifles.

Comment: It would help if you could tighten this up a little. Different predators would, I imagine, often require different approaches. Also, terrain would come into play, as would the technology level of the society doing the hunting. The Inuit hunting for food or furs did so in circumstances markedly different from the Roman gladiator confronting lions etc. for public entertainment in an arena.

Comment: @LarsBosteen just edited it

Comment: Which was the African tribe where killing a lion was a rite of the passage? Also, the pygmy alone killing an elephant is impressive: after waiting for hours until the elephant is distracted eating and the wind direction is favorable, the pygmy comes from behind, with his spear. Then  he jumps (short guy!)  and hits  the anus (thus avoiding the thick skin). The pygmy runs - his life depend on that - as the elephant becomes crazed (who wouldn't?) and aggressive to anything nearby. Then the pygmy waits as the elephant gets tired until it bleeds to death. Patience, besides having balls, is key.

Comment: @Luiz: The Masai.

Comment: You would have needed to find the soft spot.

Comment: `even many smaller caliber guns can't pierce their skin [of bears & lions & other megafauna]`. At least for bears and lions it is wrong, the skin can be relatively easy to pierce. But a small bullet may sometimes lack kinetick energy to go through the fat and muscle and to reach internal organs. An arrow may be slower, but it has way higher mass (specially if it is designed for big hunt) so higher kinetic energy. A spear can be pushed deep into the animal. If all of this fails, you keep the beast at a distance while inflicting several wounds to desangrate it. Your ideas about animals are wrong

Comment: @SJuan76 Interesting. So it was actually fairly easy to kill large predators?

Comment: *Easy* depends on circunstances. If a lion assaulted me while I was going to the pharmacy, it would certainly be very difficult for me to kill him. But if I were hunting the lion, wearing proper equipment that I had been trained to use, in good physical condition and accompanied by several buddies in the same situation my chances would be way higher. It would almost certainly not risk free, but at least reasonably doable.

Answer (score 1):

As an Assyrian king, you wouldn't defend yourself against animals. That would be the job of your bodyguard and entourage. You'd be out to entertain yourself, by killing them *(the wild animals; not your entourage)*. You would be standing in a chariot, armed with a bow, shooting at animals from a safe distance. If your first shots didn't kill the animal, you order your driver to move a bit further away - if he hadn't done that already. It was a sport, sometimes a dangerous sport. Kings (not necessarily just Assyrian kings) are known to get seriously injured or died during those hunts.

Roman gladiators didn't fight wild animals. They fought each other. What you are looking for are [bestiarii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bestiarii). They were specially trained to fight wild animals. In the social scale of things, distinctly a rung or two below gladiators.

Doesn't want to say gladiators didn't kill animals now and then, but it wasn't what they were trained for.

A bestiarius was. The job was pretty dangerous, but the bestiarius had a clear advantage over whatever kind of animal he had to face: he was trained for the job, knew (most of the time) how certain animals would react, and was properly armed to do the job well. Accidents did happen, of course.

A bestiarius was a trained specialist. Not a man [condemned to death by wild animals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damnatio_ad_bestias). Don't underestimate what one can do with just a spear.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=ashurbanipal+killing+lions&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=2ahUKEwjW8pKr28PyAhWWFFkFHUBPC4AQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1920&bih=937#imgrc=iAE6LrifcLN7AM is this just an exaggeration then? Also, I read that Achaemenid Generals would occassioonaly go on lion hunts and wear their skins as trophies, how did they do this?

Comment: A spear I think would actually be pretty much the preferred weapon against most dangerous large mammals, as an opponent with a reach advantage is really tough to beat. It might be best to just pincushion it with arrows from a distance, but you'd still need some spears to ensure it keeps that distance.

Comment: @user52024 Yes. Not always, but almost always. Attacking a lion with a knife (not even a large knife, and made out of bronze) is near suicidal. You can safely tag that as propaganda. With a sturdy spear, you've got a pretty good chance to kill. But that doesn't look very heroic.